# Ubuntu 1.14 recovery mode ((Drm_kms_helper:panic occurred,switching back to text console

Tags: lubuntu, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I updated the operating system **ubuntu. 14** (version 2.02~beta2-9))
When I restart my laptob I have this error.

.
.error

```
.
Drm_kms_helper:panic occurred,switching back to text console 
.
.
.
```

[image]

I googled and find this [tutorial](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)

But dosen't help me.I try recovery my operating system.I have not boot cd or USB .it is possible I'll go back to the last update???

Comment: Looks like something erased Ubuntu's base files. Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.

Comment: Hi.thank's.Unfortunately, I do not have a boot CD.This is possible connected to Wi-Fi of comment line???

Comment: No. If you don't have something else to boot it's going to be difficult to impossible to fix – especially from afar. A spare USB drive with ≥ 2 GB plus a working computer with an internet connection to prepare it would work too though. Network booting is another option but requires another working computer on the local network and BIOS support and is more difficult to set up.

Comment: Ok thanks. .so I have to install new ubuntu. .If it was possible that I could go back to the latest update with comment line ,It was really good.However, thank you very much

Comment: To install Ubuntu you need a bootable DVD or USB drive (or a network boot set-up) with Ubuntu… which would also allow you to run Boot-Info/Boot-Repair.